# Does the minimum slit width change with different photon frequencies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, optics, visible-light

Send white light through a vertical polarizer and then through a second horizontal gap that is just wide enough to let all the light through. Now slowly close the second gap until it becomes a slit. All the photons hitting the second slit are vertically polarized and should not make it through but as the slit slowly closed did different color light drop off sooner than other color light?

Comment: Polarization does not play a role in this experiment.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Then why does horizontally polarized light go through a horizontal slit and vertical polarized light not?

Comment: I meant in the slit. I do not think what you are saying is true. We build spectrometers with a slit and the transmission is polarization independent. Like Hagebutte said.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. Light will always go through and there is no drop-off slit (1d) or hole (2d) size for any wavelength.

---

I assume the slit to be a geometric boundary and will ignore its atomistic structure, that is, I ignore things related to the question what it actually means for a slit to be "closed" in terms of electron wavefunctions starting to overlap and such things.

---

The transmitted wave when light hits some geometrical boundary depends on the frequency. Or in other words the diffraction integral depends on the frequency.

When the slit or hole is roughly the size of the wavelength/2, the transmitted wave will approach a cylindrical (1d, slit) or spherical(2d, hole) wave.

One can also take the formula for a 1D gaussian beam and then ask for which beamwaist $w_0$ the divergence angle will approach $90°$ (though this would mean we were talking about a slit with not a hard-edge boundary but instead a soft gaussian boundary (or a gaussian hole if you want it 2D)).
This situation (having a cylindrical/spherical wave) is an illustration of the Huygens-Fresnel-Principle and, as said, the slit/hole size when this starts to happen depends on the frequency. But this does not mean that if the slit size gets even smaller, that the light will then stop to pass through. 
**The Huygens-Fresnel-Principle doesnt care how small the slit or hole is.**

As long as the slit/hole is not of size zero there will be a diffracted/transmitted wave which is not zero.

If your incoming intensity is high enough you will be able to detect light behind a slit or hole which is significantly smaller then the wavelength.

There are also special optical filters that work by this principle (e.g. UV pass/NIR block), and of course their transmission (at wavelengths (NIR) to be blocked) is not *exactly* zero, due to this.

Also, I don't think that you have to consider polarisation for this.
And also, as long as you have enough intensity you won't have to look at this in a photonic model. You just care for how the Eigenmodes look like which are governed by the classical model.

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear. We are only talking about vertically polarized photons and we know they will not go through a horizontal slit. At some point they just stopped going through and my question is asking whether or not different frequencies have different points.

Comment: Polarization doesn't care how much space is in a certain spatial direction. The electrical field vector doesn't need a certain amount of space in a certain spatial direction. They will not stop to go through, no matter how they are polarized.

Comment: then why doesn’t vertically polarized light go through horizontal slit?

Comment: But it does. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: place a horizontal polarizer after a vertical polarizer I see what you get. Is there something else I missing about cos2theta

Comment: But a polarizer - even a so called wire grid polarizer - is something completely different than just a slit

Comment: OK now you’re just evading the question. Take my same question and use polarizers instead of slits. First you have a vertical polarizer but the second horizontal polarizer has spacing so wide that most of the light still comes through. Now slowly shrink the spacing of the second horizontal polarizer until all the light is squeezed out. At what point did that happen and did different colors drop out sooner than other colors?

Comment: I see, so you mean indeed wiregrid. But then I suggest you make a new question?! I'm not sure if my answer above holds in the case of a "conductive slit array" because you may not arrive at the usual diffraction integrals due to having large values of divergence(epsilon(x,y,z)E) in such  a case. But assuming(!) you would nevertheless arrive at the usual wave equation / diffraction integrals (which I dont know, and doubt actually) you could apply all what I wrote above: then the light in the gaps would diffract as cylindrical waves leading to fast attenuation compared to more collimated light

Comment: I still think you are confusing things here. The experiment is completely different if you "build" a variable spacing wiregrid polarizer (if that is even possible). @hagebutte is completely correct about everything, and a slit has 0 selection properties when it comes to polarization.

Comment: @JoséAndrade as the horizontal gap width closes what eventually stops the light from coming through? Don’t tell me this doesn’t happen because it’s obvious that no vertically polarized light comes through the horizontal polarizer. Why not and at what width did it stop? These are questions that can be answered. Who has that technical data?

Comment: A wiregrid polarizer is a completely different thing from a slit. A wiregrid polarizer is an object that has electrical properties and the skin current in the wires "rectifies" the electromagnetic field! It's not the same as a slit! What stops the light passing through a slit? Like @hagebutte said you are now getting into the quantum realm. But you can probably solve it using Maxwell equations. So, solve the maxwell equations, you will get your answer to your question.

Comment: Or answering it differently. "Who has that technical data?": Maxwell equations.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Photons reaching a slit either go through or they don’t. If they do go through then they become polarized with the slit. Same is true for a wire grid polarizers (a lot of slits). Photons reaching the polarizer either go through or they don’t. When they do go through they too become polarized. It doesn’t matter what you want to call them my question still stands. Photons that are polarized vertical will not pass through slits or polarizers that are polarized horizontally. If you sprayed the gaps light will pass through no matter how it’s polarized. At what distance did this happen?

Comment: I am really sorry but I am finding this ridiculous. I do not have to give EM classes to you and you seem to know more about light propagation and light-matter interaction than me and @hagebutte. So, as you know better, and seem to know of data that backs up your claims, then you answer your own question. So, please continue to ignore my comments on the properties of a wiregrid polarizer and the fact that a slit has no polarization selection properties.